# IIS to allow only sharepoint online access its app content

Tags: security, iis, sharepoint

I have a private page on iis website that I want to display on sharepoint online website in web part in iframe but I dont want anyone else to get to that page externally. For security reasons.

Is there way I can allow only sharepoint online access the iis page?
Or any other recommendations?

Comment: There is no relevant setting in IIS for restricting SharePoint. But you can refer to this about restrict or allow a web site access to some IP addresses in IIS: https://www.ryadel.com/en/iis-restrict-web-site-access-ip-address-mask-block-deny-allow-how-to/.

Comment: Add authentication to your page. But to be honest, your question lacks details. What kind of "page" is the page you target? What's the technical stack of this page? Why would you use an iframe compared to a webpart that has the knowledge to grab the data from your backend ? Actually, what you ask has nothing to do with SharePoint

Answer (score 0):

I once saw an answer that you can use SharePoint permissions to restrict access to your pages on IIS. You can use a SharePoint site or page that contains an iframe that displays the IIS page, and then set permissions on that site or page to allow only specific users or groups to view it. Link: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164447/allow-only-certain-users-access-to-a-site.

But it is not possible to achieve what you said, only allowing SharePoint Online to access IIS pages.

Comment: I will look into this and see if it can work.

Comment: I modified the code for the applicaiton to check how the request is coming in and redirect to login screen if its not within iframe. But after doing so came to another problem, which is when the iis hosted application (asp.net, vb) is firing button click clode behind it it erroring out when in sharepoint online iframe, but when it is not in sharepoint online, in standard html page it is able to fire the button client event without erroring out. dont know if sharepoint online is blocking code execution.

Comment: Alright, this is a new problem, and it's not clear from the description alone what's going on. So you should create a new case. In addition to describing the problem, you also need to provide code (preferably the minimum reproducible code), error screenshots and add appropriate tags. With more detailed information and the correct tag, community members can see and help you.

Comment: Since you develop the page, why don't you develop a webparT?